# Quartz JobDetailMap not being applied to Job Class

Tags: quartz-scheduler, job-scheduling

I am trying to programmatically create a quartz job and trigger. Here is the code I'm using:

```
    JobDetail jobDetail = new JobDetail("test","testgroup",jobClass);
    jobDetail.setJobDataMap(new JobDataMap(jobDataAsMap));

    CronTriggerBean ctb = new CronTriggerBean();
    ctb.setCronExpression(cronExpression);
    ctb.setJobDetail(jobDetail);
    ctb.setName("testTrigger");

    scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, ctb);
```

I have confirmed via the debugger that the map does indeed have data, but for some odd reason, the data in that map never gets applied to the jobClass instance that the trigger uses. I do have the corresponding setters in that class. Everything remains null, however.

Does anyone have an idea of what I might be missing?

Comment: What kind of objects do you store in your JobData map? Try to use only Strings and see if it works then. Otherwise, your code looks good. I would also try to see what happens when you set the JobDataMap on the trigger.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out why the JobDataMap wasn't getting applied - my Job class wasn't extending QuartzJobBean. Once I fixed that everything begain functioning as expected.